# Finding the URL of a WebBrowser

Tags: excel, google-maps, url, excel-2010, webbrowser-control

I have embedded a google world map into an excel 2010 sheet. Pressing CommandButton1 loads this map with this code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    link_name = "https://www.google.com/maps"
    Call Sheets("Sheet3").WebBrowser1.Navigate(link_name)
End Sub
```

When clicking on a country on this map, the url changes to something like this:
https://www.google.com/maps/place/New+Zealand/...

I want to be able to find the url in order to extract the country which was clicked on.

How do I get the url of WebBrowser1 as a string?

I do not have excel 2013 which would obviously make using maps easier.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the URL with the `.LocationURL` property. Ie.:

```
Dim WebBrowserURL As String

WebBrowserURL = Sheets("Sheet3").WebBrowser1.LocationURL

MsgBox WebBrowserURL
```

Regards,